# windows form and subform routine

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms method that gets called:

```
// fire up the form 
ViewportRenumberingForm form = new ViewportRenumberingForm(pickedRef, doc);
form.ShowDialog();
```

Then inside of that form I have a routine that gets run:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        renumberViewports();
    }
```

now if during execution of `renumberViewports()` it encounters a certain condition I am asking it to initiate a sub form to get user input on how to proceed:

```
if (openAdditionalForm)
{
    ViewportRenumberingForm2 subForm = new ViewportRenumberingForm2();
    var result = subForm.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // get all values preserved after close
        bool selected = subForm.ReturnSelected;
        bool unselected = subForm.ReturnUnselected;

        if (selected)
        {
            //do something
        }
        if (unselected)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

Now, the question is: When user hits Cancel I want to return to my main form and basically start over. That means that user can re-enter any information and hit that `btnOK_Click()` and `renumberViewports()` will get executed again. It's basically that I want ability for user to just acknowledge that their current input will cause an error, show them that in a sub form, allow them to cancel to re-enter inputs. 
Then i want to re-execute it and close the form if there are no errors.

Right now, i got everything up to the Cancel input working. When user hits Cancel I return to my main form, but hitting OK on it, doesnt re-execute the `renumberViewports()` command.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This should be a compile error, `result` isn't defined where the `else if` can see it.

Comment: i fixed that. i was just hastily copying parts of the code and misplaced some brackets. my bad.

Comment: Please tell us what is the value of the property DialogResult of the btnOK and what are the values of the properties AcceptButton and CancelButton on the form where the btnOK is defined

Comment: What happens if you put `renumberViewports();` under the `this.Show();` in the cancel part?

Comment: @RonBeyer well I am guessing that it will try to re-execute automatically. That will take the ability of user to re-enter information into the main form and then try to re-execute.

Comment: I guess its confusing what you are saying. Are you saying that if they hit "cancel" on `ViewportRenumberingForm2` you can't hit the OK button again on `ViewportRenumberingForm`? Do you disable the button somewhere?

Comment: no i didnt disable the button. but hitting it again, doesnt do anything.

Comment: Have you tried adding a break point and stepping through the code?

Comment: Isn't your form already being displayed? Why are you calling Show again? Is your first form hidden at some point that we do not see?

Comment: yes, I hide it when I know that a sub-form will get initiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, in your `renumberViewports()` method, change your `DialogResult.Cancel` conditional block to this:

```
else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    // this will close this form and set the result to 'Cancel'
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

Then, in you main form, instead of simply:

```
ViewportRenumberingForm form = new ViewportRenumberingForm(pickedRef, doc);
form.ShowDialog();
```

... I would change that to a loop that keeps reopening the `ViewportRenumberingForm` form until the result is not `Cancel`:

```
DialogResult result = DialogResult.Cancel;
while (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    ViewportRenumberingForm form = new ViewportRenumberingForm(pickedRef, doc);
    result = form.ShowDialog();
}
```